# Login into Mysql without startx

Tags: linux, command-line, mysql, mysql-connection

I have had install Damn small Linux(DSL) 10 in Virtual Box with MySQL 5. I created already a database with a Table and Data in it. I can access it over the terminal with the following line:

```
mysql -u dsl
```

During this, DSL is startes with startx (GUI). But if I start DSL without startx (its not anymore in .bash_profile) I'll get access to DSL over the Terminal (tty1) automatically.

The Problem at this point. If DSL started without startx, its not possible to get access to Mysql by give in the line:

```
mysql -u dsl
```

The Screenshot is here:
[image]
How its possible to solve this problem.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but these days, VirtualBox+DSL is very often replaceable by a much lighter (and faster to start) Docker container. You'll find containers with [MySQL pre-installed](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) and other containers with an [admin interface to it](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker).

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a PATH issue. When you type a command name in the terminal like you do when typing mysql, actually the terminal is trying to find it in folder specified in the PATH variable, and I guess that variable doesn't contain the same folder when you're running X and when you are not.

When you are running with X, and you can use mysql, type `whereis -b mysql`, you should get something like `/path/to/mysql` or similar.

Then go into your no-X session and type that full path `/path/to/mysql  -u dsl` and it should work.
To make it permanent you have to modify your .bash_profile if you are using bash. Write a line like this : `export PATH='/path/to:$PATH` and then from the command line `. .bash_profile` or reconnect yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to add

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

to your PATH by running

```
export PATH=$PATH;/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

else by adding this path to your ~/.bash_profile

But you can also type the whole path to mysql utility

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u dsl
```

By default installing Mysql it's not updating by anyway the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need to do it regularly, the easiest way is to invoke  `mysql` with the full path as

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u dsl
```